EventBridge Pipes with DynamoDB Stream - losing payload during target input transform
I have set up an EventBridge pipe that takes the latest insert or modify event on a DynamoDB instance's Stream, formats the event's payload to remove DynamoDB's data type notation, and pass a JSON dictionary to my Step Functions state machine.
For some reason, during the target input transform, the output is just the input transformer with empty strings instead of a json dict with the formatted event data. I have attached the EventBridge logs for similarly structured events below.
DynamoDB Stream Configuration

Event filtering parameter
{
  "eventName": ["INSERT", "MODIFY"]
}

Event enrichment: None applicable
Sample Input Payload
{
  "Records": [{
    "eventID": "2d8a498addef68cb9478bf386fee1028",
    "eventName": "MODIFY",
    "eventVersion": "1.1",
    "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
    "awsRegion": "ap-south-1",
    "dynamodb": {
      "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1724904619,
      "Keys": {
        "jobTime": {
          "S": "20240827T122706Z"
        },
        "jobId": {
          "S": "j345jfn89454nj9aa"
        }
      },
      "NewImage": {
        "jobId": {
          "S": "j345jfn89454nj9aa"
        },
        "jobTime": {
          "S": "20240827T122706Z"
        },
        "jobSpec": {
          "M": {
            "s3Uri": {
              "S": "s3://dummy-bucket/jhvfbhbfv38e78247/fbdkbcjdnknv/input/pyspark-tutorial.zip"
            },
            "reviewComment": {
              "S": ""
            },
            "reviewerAssigned": {
              "S": "ANY"
            },
            "noSyntheticComment": {
              "S": "cuz swagg"
            },
            "reviewStatus": {
              "S": "INPUTPENDING"
            },
            "user": {
              "S": "example@gmail.com"
            },
            "command": {
              "S": "./runapp.sh"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "SequenceNumber": "8047900000801151401189110",
      "SizeBytes": 312,
      "StreamViewType": "NEW_IMAGE"
    },
    "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-south-1:1234567890:table/pipeline-jobs/stream/2024-08-27T10:32:23.996"
  }]
}

Input Transformer
{
  "notify": "NEW_INPUT",
  "jobId": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobId.S>,
  "jobTime": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobTime.S>,
  "jobSpec": {
    "s3Uri": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobSpec.M.s3Uri.S>,
    "command": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobSpec.M.command.S>,
    "noSyntheticComment": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobSpec.M.noSyntheticComment.S>,
    "user": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobSpec.M.user.S>,
    "reviewStatus": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobSpec.M.reviewStatus.S>,
    "reviewComment": <$.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.jobSpec.M.reviewComment.S>
  }
}

Output as seen in section
{
  "notify": "NEW_INPUT",
  "jobId": "j345jfn89454nj9aa",
  "jobTime": "20240827T122706Z",
  "jobSpec": {
    "s3Uri": "s3://dummy-bucket/jhvfbhbfv38e78247/fbdkbcjdnknv/input/pyspark-tutorial.zip",
    "command": "./runapp.sh",
    "noSyntheticComment": "cuz swagg",
    "user": "example@gmail.com",
    "reviewStatus": "INPUTPENDING",
    "reviewComment": ""
  }
}

EventBridge Logs (deidentified)
{
    "resourceArn": "arn:aws:pipes:ap-south-1:1234567890:pipe/dummy-trigger-input-approval-flow-pipe",
    "timestamp": 1724904620316,
    "executionId": "3abf625-as2-4109-9e5a-05ac2653haj",
    "messageType": "ExecutionStarted",
    "logLevel": "INFO",
    "payload": "{\"Records\":[{\"eventID\":\"2d8a498addef68cb9478bf386fee1028\",\"eventName\":\"MODIFY\",\"eventVersion\":\"1.1\",\"eventSource\":\"aws:dynamodb\",\"awsRegion\":\"ap-south-1\",\"dynamodb\":{\"ApproximateCreationDateTime\":1724904619,\"Keys\":{\"jobTime\":{\"S\":\"20240827T122706Z\"},\"jobId\":{\"S\":\"j345jfn89454nj9aa\"}},\"NewImage\":{\"jobId\":{\"S\":\"j345jfn89454nj9aa\"},\"jobTime\":{\"S\":\"20240827T122706Z\"},\"jobSpec\":{\"M\":{\"s3Uri\":{\"S\":\"s3://dummy-jobs/jhvfbhbfv38e78247/fbdkbcjdnknv/input/pyspark-tutorial.zip\"},\"reviewComment\":{\"S\":\"\"},\"reviewerAssigned\":{\"S\":\"ANY\"},\"noSyntheticComment\":{\"S\":\"cuz swagg\"},\"reviewStatus\":{\"S\":\"INPUTPENDING\"},\"user\":{\"S\":\"example@gmail.com\"},\"command\":{\"S\":\"./runapp.sh\"}}}},\"SequenceNumber\":\"8047900000801151401189110\",\"SizeBytes\":312,\"StreamViewType\":\"NEW_IMAGE\"},\"eventSourceARN\":\"arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-south-1:1234567890:table/dummy-jobs/stream/2024-08-27T10:32:23.996\"}]}"
}

{
    "resourceArn": "arn:aws:pipes:ap-south-1:1234567890:pipe/dummy-trigger-input-approval-flow-pipe",
    "timestamp": 1724904620325,
    "executionId": "3abf625-as2-4109-9e5a-05ac2653haj",
    "messageType": "TargetStageEntered",
    "logLevel": "INFO"
}

{
    "resourceArn": "arn:aws:pipes:ap-south-1:1234567890:pipe/dummy-trigger-input-approval-flow-pipe",
    "timestamp": 1724904620443,
    "executionId": "3abf625-as2-4109-9e5a-05ac2653haj",
    "messageType": "TargetStageSucceeded",
    "logLevel": "INFO",
    "payload": "" <<< missing payload!
}

{
    "resourceArn": "arn:aws:pipes:ap-south-1:1234567890:pipe/dummy-trigger-input-approval-flow-pipe",
    "timestamp": 1724904620443,
    "executionId": "3abf625-as2-4109-9e5a-05ac2653haj",
    "messageType": "ExecutionSucceeded",
    "logLevel": "INFO"
}

